# How to put each element from array as a parameter of SQL query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array like this

```
matches = [1,2,3,4]
```

now i want to put that array in my query

```
.where(name LIKE ? AND last_name LIKE ? AND skin LIKE ?, matches[0], matches[1], matches[2]...)
```

sometime my query is

```
name LIKE ? AND last_name LIKE ?
```

for that only have to be the match two

```
matches[0], matches[1]
```

or

`name LIKE ?`  for this only have to be the match `matches[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use splat-operator. It will convert array to arguments

```rb
matches = %w[a b c]


Person.where('name LIKE ? AND last_name LIKE ? AND skin LIKE ?', *matches)

Person.where('name LIKE ? AND last_name LIKE ?', *matches[0..1])
```

Or may be hash with double splat

```rb
matches = { last_name: 'a',  name: 'b',  skin: 'c' }

Person.where('name :name ? AND last_name LIKE :last_name AND skin LIKE :skin', **matches)

Person.where('name :name ? AND last_name LIKE :last_name', **matches.slice(:name, :last_name))
```